# Solidity: Contract should be marked as abstract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I am trying to write a Smart Contract to generate Staking Rewards for an existing Cryptocurrency
But I've been getting this error

> Contract "Stakeable" should be marked as abstract

How do I fix this?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
// import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
contract Stakeable is ERC20, Ownable{
        using SafeMath for uint256;
    
        string private constant _name = "Schrodinger";
        string private constant _symbol = "Kitty Dinger";
        
        /**
        * @notice We usually require to know who are all the stakeholders.
        */
        address[] internal stakeholders;
    
        /**
         * @notice The stakes for each stakeholder.
         */
        mapping(address => uint256) internal stakes;
    
        /**
         * @notice The accumulated rewards for each stakeholder.
         */
        mapping(address => uint256) internal rewards;
    
        /**
        * @notice The constructor for the Staking Token.
        * @param _owner The address to receive all tokens on construction.
        * @param _supply The amount of tokens to mint on construction.
        */
    
        constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_, address _owner, uint256 _supply)
        {    
            name_ = _name;
            symbol_ = _symbol;
            _mint(_owner, _supply);
        }
```

Comment: Btw in solidity v0.8.0+ you don't have to use `SafeMatch` library anymore. Solidity is checking over/underflows automatically. In case you would like to turn it off for some part, use `unchecked { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

@ashhanai has a good point.

You are inheriting your contract from ERC20 but you didn't call the ERC20 constructor. If you'll update your constructor as like @ashhanai's suggestion, probably the problem will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the `name` and `symbol` properties directly, add call to `ERC20` constructor instead.

Update constructor code:

```
constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_, address _owner, uint256 _supply) ERC20(name_, symbol_)
    {    
        _mint(_owner, _supply);
    }
```